# Strange InputDispatcher error "Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x8"

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I just created an android app (API 7), with two classes (Launcher and Menu).
Launcher has couple lines:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.bce.tip.core.MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Menu is activity and has this:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.menu);  
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() { 
      super.onDestroy();     
  }
}
```

And I get errors like these, no stack trace before it...

```
01-03 11:28:47.279: WARN/ActivityManager(164): No content provider found for:
01-03 11:28:47.399: WARN/ActivityManager(164): No content provider found for: 
01-03 11:28:47.499: ERROR/InputDispatcher(164): channel '4085fe50 com.bce.tip/com.bce.tip.core.MenuActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-03 11:28:47.499: ERROR/InputDispatcher(164): channel '4085fe50 com.bce.tip/com.bce.tip.core.MenuActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!`
```

or this

```
01-03 11:17:55.339: ERROR/InputDispatcher(164): channel '409467f0 com.sec.android.app.dialertab/com.sec.android.app.dialertab.DialerTabActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-03 11:17:55.339: ERROR/InputDispatcher(164): channel '409467f0 com.sec.android.app.dialertab/com.sec.android.app.dialertab.DialerTabActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".Launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bce.tip.core.MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>


</application>
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Please edit your post and include the _full_ MenuActivity.java file.

Comment: There is only onCreate and onDestroy

Comment: Not sure if it is the cause, but I noticed that your MenuActivity class is named HomeActivity!

Comment: Very strange problem. I just tested your code and it works fine here. If you search for the error string on SO you will find that other people have also encountered this error message, but no clear solution. Are there any other errors before this error? And does your app continue to run or does it force close?

Comment: if you found answer please post